# Hibernate does not see already inserted data

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, dao

My problem is that Hibernate does not read any data from DB if it was already inserted manually (I'm using MySQL). What I mean is that I dropped PATIENTS table and then Hibernate created it for me and after that I inserted data from PATIENTS.sql. When I launch my application there are no patients displayed in, for example, show_patients.jsp. But I still can access my application via login page using inserted records.

Here is my method in @Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/therapist/showPatients", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showExistingPatients(ModelMap map) {
    List<Patient> patientsList = userService.getAllPatients();
    map.addAttribute("patientsList", patientsList);
    return "therapist/show_patients";
}
```

Here is my method in UserDAOImpl:

```
public List<Patient> selectAllPatients(){
    DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Patient.class);
    List<Patient> patients = null;
    try{
        patients = getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria);
    } catch (DataAccessException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return patients;
}
```

The only way I can see any patients in show_patients.jsp is to add new patient via my application allowing Hiberante to save it. So my question is if there is any condition why this works only after Hibernate's save() or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: After inserting PATIENTS.sql can you see it by a manual select ? You can try to activate the show_sql=true and then execute the query manualy and see happend

Comment: If I'm doing manual selects from MySQL Workbench everithing is fine. I can see all the data.

Comment: Can you see both sets of data (manually inserted and hibernate) in the same table when using MySQL Workbench?

Comment: Yes. I think pasha701 is right and cashe is involved somehow, because now I can see both manually inserted and hibernate-inserted data in my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two variants:

1. Query cache is turned on in Hibernate. Check settings; maybe, "evict" can be used for remove query results from cache.
2. Maybe, web page caching present on WebServer or browser settings, check required.